# Добавление записи в связанный таблицы ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Добрый день, при разработке MVC-приложения возникла следующая задача: есть производственные карты, описывающие какую-то продукцию и материалы, из которых создаётся эта самая продукция.
В БД есть следующие связанные таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На их основе сформировал несколько моделей

Модель TechnologicalCard, описывающая технологическую карту

```
namespace AccountingPlusProject.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class TechnologicalCard
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public TechnologicalCard()
    {
        this.ReferenceMaterials = new HashSet<ReferenceMaterial>();
    }

    public int IdTechnologicalCard { get; set; }
    public string NameProduct { get; set; }
    public string IdHeadDepartment { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ReferenceMaterial> ReferenceMaterials { get; set; }
}
}
```

Модель ReferenceMaterial, описывающая материалы, использующиеся в картах

```
namespace AccountingPlusProject.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class ReferenceMaterial
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ReferenceMaterial()
    {
        this.TechnologicalCards = new HashSet<TechnologicalCard>();
    }

    public int IdMaterial { get; set; }
    public string NameMaterial { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TechnologicalCard> TechnologicalCards { get; set; }

    public class CardEditModel
    {
        public TechnologicalCard Card { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ReferenceMaterial> Members { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ReferenceMaterial> NonMembers { get; set; }
    }

    public class CardModificationModel
    {
        public int[] IdsToAdd { get; set; }
        public int[] IdsToDelete { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

В TechnologicalCardController есть GET метод для добавления материалов в карту или удаления материалов из карты (на основе двух массивов идентификаторов members и nonmembers соответственно)

```
public ActionResult EditMaterial(int id = 3) // передаваемый id карты = 3 только для теста
    {      
        TechnologicalCard card = db.TechnologicalCards.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdTechnologicalCard == id);
        int[] memberIDs = card.ReferenceMaterials.Select(m => m.IdMaterial).ToArray();

        IEnumerable<ReferenceMaterial> members = db.ReferenceMaterials.Where(x => memberIDs.Any(y => y == x.IdMaterial));
        IEnumerable<ReferenceMaterial> nonMembers = db.ReferenceMaterials.Except(members);
        return View(new CardEditModel
        {
            Card = card,
            Members = members,
            NonMembers = nonMembers
        });
    }
```

Код непосредственно View

```
@using AccountingPlusProject.Models
@model ReferenceMaterial.CardEditModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>-</h2>
@Html.ValidationSummary()
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<input type="hidden" name="roleName" value="@Model.Card.IdTechnologicalCard" />
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Add to card<b>@Model.Card.IdTechnologicalCard</b></div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        @if (Model.NonMembers.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">!</td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            foreach (ReferenceMaterial material in Model.NonMembers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@material.NameMaterial</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="IdsToAdd" value="@material.IdMaterial">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Delete from card<b>@Model.Card.IdTechnologicalCard</b></div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        @if (Model.Members.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">нету</td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            foreach (ReferenceMaterial material in Model.Members)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@material.NameMaterial</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="IdsToDelete" value="@material.IdMaterial">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default"     })
}
```

Так представление выглядит в браузере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбранные checkbox передают IdsToDelete или IdsToAdd, по которым будут удаляться или добавляться материалы в таблицу SelectedMaterial, но не знаю, как это сделать в POST версии метода EditMaterial, помогите разобраться в этом. Как вытаскивать значения понял, а вот как вставлять или удалять до сих пор загадка.

Сам думал сделать что-то подобное, но уж слишком черновой вариант

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditMaterial(CardModificationModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TechnologicalCard card = db.TechnologicalCards.Where(c => c.IdTechnologicalCard == 3).FirstOrDefault();
            foreach (int materialId in model.IdsToAdd ?? new int[] { })
            {
                ReferenceMaterial material = db.ReferenceMaterials.Where(m => m.IdMaterial == materialId).First();
                card.ReferenceMaterials.Add(material);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            foreach (int materialId in model.IdsToDelete ?? new int[] { })
            {
                ReferenceMaterial material = db.ReferenceMaterials.Where(m => m.IdMaterial == materialId).First();
                card.ReferenceMaterials.Remove(material);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View("Error", new string[] { "Роль не найдена" });
    }
```